# How to access 32 bit dll from 64-bit process or 64-bit dll

Tags: c++, dll, com, corba, dcom

I have a java program which make use of JNI to access "dll" file written in C++.Initially I had a problem accessing "dll" using JNI, but when I came to know about "DLL export", used it and was able to call function encapsulated inside "dll".Now I am only able to call function written inside "64-bit dll" via c++ code linked through java . If I tried to call function embedded inside a 32 bit dll,the compiler produce an error or do not give result at all. After an hour of "error and compilation" play, I found that using 64-bit jdk and its JNI feature I cannot call 32-bit dll written in c++. I have to make use of 32-bit jdk for accessing 32 bit dll via its JNI.
  Now I am looking for a solution using which I can access even 32 bit dll( my legacy code is written in 32 bit dll and it cant be compiled into 64-bit dll)
from 64-bit jdk. or in simple words I am looking for such code using which I can access 32 bit dll code written in c++ from 64 bit process or dll. Along with it I would like to mention that I have gone through all the solutions provide by "stackoverflow" to "access -32 bit dll from 64 bit process", but I did not find any of them resourceful to me. They mention about "COM" and "Surrogate Process",
but I am not able to connect how this thing can be use to tackle a problem I have. So can any one suggest me a pure solution or guidance or "reference books" for accessing 32 bit dll from 64 bit dll.

Note: please do not downcast the vote for this question as I truly say that there is no proper solution provied so far in "stack overflow" for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a surrogate, there's plenty of information on how you can setup one to have the component loaded in its required architecture.

The thing is that if you have interfaces that don't support marshaling, or the component has thread- or process-local behavior, it will not work correctly. So, only components that are ready to be used remotely will work.

Check your component before even trying the surrogate approach.

Comment: Thanks @Paulo for your valuable comment. Since I am new to all this like marshalling , surrogate so what you said went over my head. Would you mind to refer me some books or reference material for this..

Answer (score -1):

You simply cannot do what you're asking, and there are lots of resources that explain this. A 64-bit process can only call 64-bit DLLs, and the same goes for 32-bit. You cannot mix and match. This is just how Windows (and Linux) work.

The correct solution is to compile the C++ code into both 32 and 64 bit DLLs.

Comment: I agree with your view @Jonathon but what if I want to call  legacy code available in  32-bit only . Numerous websites like stackover flow  suggest me that COM can be the solution for such cases provided 32-bit and 64-bit are run as separate process.  Can you add your view on that?

Comment: I think introducing COM into this is going to be far more pain than dealing with the 32-bit vs 64-bit restriction. Is there any reason you can't just stick with running a 32-bit process? Many applications do this to deal with legacy 32-bit code.